# Discount strategy in shopping cart and orders

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, e-commerce

I am trying to implement a system that can handle multiple discounts applied to my cart/completed orders. I have applied a strategy type pattern to encapsulate the processing of the discounts within the discounts.

I have come up with the following: an abstract discount base class with subclasses making up the concrete discounts. These are then applied to either an order/cart object and will process the contents of the order/cart when added to the cart/order.

Would love some comments on the code attached. Various protected constructors and members marked "virtual" needed for nhibernate.

Chev

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace CodeCollective.RaceFace.DiscountEngine
{
[TestFixture]
public class TestAll
{
    #region Tests

    [Test]
    public void Can_Add_Items_To_Cart()
    {
        Cart cart = LoadCart();

        // display the cart contents
        foreach (LineItem lineItem in cart.LineItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Product: {0}\t Price: {1:c}\t Quantity: {2} \t Subtotal: {4:c} \t Discount: {3:c} \t| Discounts Applied: {5}", lineItem.Product.Name, lineItem.Product.Price, lineItem.Quantity, lineItem.DiscountAmount, lineItem.Subtotal, lineItem.Discounts.Count);
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_Add_Items_To_An_Order()
    {
        // create the cart
        Order order = new Order(new Member("Chev"));

        // add items to the cart
        GenericProduct hat = new GenericProduct("Cap", 110m);
        order.AddLineItem(hat, 5);

        EventItem race = new EventItem("Ticket", 90m);
        order.AddLineItem(race, 1);

        // add discounts 
        Discount percentageOff = new PercentageOffDiscount("10% off all items", 0.10m);
        percentageOff.CanBeUsedInJuntionWithOtherDiscounts = false;
        order.AddDiscount(percentageOff);

        Discount spendXgetY = new SpendMoreThanXGetYDiscount("Spend more than R100 get 10% off", 100m, 0.1m);
        spendXgetY.SupercedesOtherDiscounts = true;
        order.AddDiscount(spendXgetY);

        Discount buyXGetY = new BuyXGetYFree("Buy 4 hats get 2 hat free", new List<Product> { hat }, 4, 2);
        buyXGetY.CanBeUsedInJuntionWithOtherDiscounts = false;
        buyXGetY.SupercedesOtherDiscounts = true;
        order.AddDiscount(buyXGetY);

        // display the cart contents
        foreach (LineItem lineItem in order.LineItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Product: {0}\t Price: {1:c}\t Quantity: {2} \t Subtotal: {4:c} \t Discount: {3:c} \t| Discounts Applied: {5}", lineItem.Product.Name, lineItem.Product.Price, lineItem.Quantity, lineItem.DiscountAmount, lineItem.Subtotal, lineItem.Discounts.Count);
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_Process_A_Cart_Into_An_Order()
    {
        Cart cart = LoadCart();

        Order order = ProcessCartToOrder(cart);

        // display the cart contents
        foreach (LineItem lineItem in order.LineItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Product: {0}\t Price: {1:c}\t Quantity: {2} \t Subtotal: {4:c} \t Discount: {3:c} \t| Discounts Applied: {5}", lineItem.Product.Name, lineItem.Product.Price, lineItem.Quantity, lineItem.DiscountAmount, lineItem.Subtotal, lineItem.Discounts.Count);
        }
    }

    private static Cart LoadCart()
    {
        // create the cart
        Cart cart = new Cart(new Member("Chev"));

        // add items to the cart
        GenericProduct hat = new GenericProduct("Cap", 110m);
        cart.AddLineItem(hat, 5);

        EventItem race = new EventItem("Ticket", 90m);
        cart.AddLineItem(race, 1);

        // add discounts 
        Discount percentageOff = new PercentageOffDiscount("10% off all items", 0.10m);
        percentageOff.CanBeUsedInJuntionWithOtherDiscounts = false;
        cart.AddDiscount(percentageOff);

        Discount spendXgetY = new SpendMoreThanXGetYDiscount("Spend more than R100 get 10% off", 100m, 0.1m);
        spendXgetY.SupercedesOtherDiscounts = true;
        cart.AddDiscount(spendXgetY);

        Discount buyXGetY = new BuyXGetYFree("Buy 4 hats get 2 hat free", new List<Product> { hat }, 4, 2);
        buyXGetY.CanBeUsedInJuntionWithOtherDiscounts = false;
        buyXGetY.SupercedesOtherDiscounts = true;
        cart.AddDiscount(buyXGetY);

        return cart;
    }

    private static Order ProcessCartToOrder(Cart cart)
    {
        Order order = new Order(cart.Member);
        foreach(LineItem lineItem in cart.LineItems)
        {
            order.AddLineItem(lineItem.Product, lineItem.Quantity);
            foreach(Discount discount in lineItem.Discounts)
            {
                order.AddDiscount(discount);    
            }
        }
        return order;
    }

    #endregion
}

#region Discounts

[Serializable]
public abstract class Discount : EntityBase
{
    protected internal Discount()
    {
    }

    public Discount(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public virtual bool CanBeUsedInJuntionWithOtherDiscounts { get; set; }
    public virtual bool SupercedesOtherDiscounts { get; set; }
    public abstract OrderBase ApplyDiscount();
    public virtual OrderBase OrderBase { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; private set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class PercentageOffDiscount : Discount
{
    protected internal PercentageOffDiscount()
    {
    }

    public PercentageOffDiscount(string name, decimal discountPercentage)
        : base(name)
    {
        DiscountPercentage = discountPercentage;
    }

    public override OrderBase ApplyDiscount()
    {
        // custom processing
        foreach (LineItem lineItem in OrderBase.LineItems)
        {
            lineItem.DiscountAmount = lineItem.Product.Price * DiscountPercentage;
            lineItem.AddDiscount(this);
        }
        return OrderBase;
    }

    public virtual decimal DiscountPercentage { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class BuyXGetYFree : Discount
{
    protected internal BuyXGetYFree()
    {
    }

    public BuyXGetYFree(string name, IList<Product> applicableProducts, int x, int y)
        : base(name)
    {
        ApplicableProducts = applicableProducts;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public override OrderBase ApplyDiscount()
    {
        // custom processing
        foreach (LineItem lineItem in OrderBase.LineItems)
        {
            if(ApplicableProducts.Contains(lineItem.Product) && lineItem.Quantity > X)
            {
                lineItem.DiscountAmount += ((lineItem.Quantity / X) * Y) * lineItem.Product.Price;
                lineItem.AddDiscount(this);    
            }
        }
        return OrderBase;
    }

    public virtual IList<Product> ApplicableProducts { get; set; }
    public virtual int X { get; set; }
    public virtual int Y { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class SpendMoreThanXGetYDiscount : Discount
{
    protected internal SpendMoreThanXGetYDiscount()
    {
    }

    public SpendMoreThanXGetYDiscount(string name, decimal threshold, decimal discountPercentage)
        : base(name)
    {
        Threshold = threshold;
        DiscountPercentage = discountPercentage;
    }

    public override OrderBase ApplyDiscount()
    {
        // if the total for the cart/order is more than x apply discount
        if(OrderBase.GrossTotal > Threshold)
        {
            // custom processing
            foreach (LineItem lineItem in OrderBase.LineItems)
            {
                lineItem.DiscountAmount += lineItem.Product.Price * DiscountPercentage;
                lineItem.AddDiscount(this);
            }
        }
        return OrderBase;
    }

    public virtual decimal Threshold { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal DiscountPercentage { get; set; }
}

#endregion

#region Order

[Serializable]
public abstract class OrderBase : EntityBase
{
    private IList<LineItem> _LineItems = new List<LineItem>();
    private IList<Discount> _Discounts = new List<Discount>();

    protected internal OrderBase() { }

    protected OrderBase(Member member)
    {
        Member = member;
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }

    public LineItem AddLineItem(Product product, int quantity)
    {
        LineItem lineItem = new LineItem(this, product, quantity);
        _LineItems.Add(lineItem);
        return lineItem;
    }

    public void AddDiscount(Discount discount)
    {
        discount.OrderBase = this;
        discount.ApplyDiscount();
        _Discounts.Add(discount);
    }

    public virtual decimal GrossTotal
    {
        get
        {
            return LineItems
                .Sum(x => x.Product.Price * x.Quantity);
        }
    }
    public virtual DateTime DateCreated { get; private set; }
    public IList<LineItem> LineItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _LineItems;
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Order : OrderBase
{
    protected internal Order() { }

    public Order(Member member)
        : base(member)
    {
    }
}

#endregion

#region LineItems

[Serializable]
public class LineItem : EntityBase
{
    private IList<Discount> _Discounts = new List<Discount>();

    protected internal LineItem() { }

    public LineItem(OrderBase order, Product product, int quantity)
    {
        Order = order;
        Product = product;
        Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public virtual void AddDiscount(Discount discount)
    {
        _Discounts.Add(discount);
    }

    public virtual OrderBase Order { get; private set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; private set; }
    public virtual int Quantity { get; private set; }
    public virtual decimal DiscountAmount { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Subtotal
    {
        get { return (Product.Price*Quantity) - DiscountAmount; }
    }
    public virtual IList<Discount> Discounts
    {
        get { return _Discounts.ToList().AsReadOnly(); }
    }
}
#endregion

#region Member

[Serializable]
public class Member : EntityBase
{
    protected internal Member() { }

    public Member(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

#endregion

#region Cart

[Serializable]
public class Cart : OrderBase
{
    protected internal Cart()
    {
    }

    public Cart(Member member)
        : base(member)
    {
    }
}

#endregion

#region Products

[Serializable]
public abstract class Product : EntityBase
{
    protected internal Product()
    {
    }

    public Product(string name, decimal price)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
    }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
}

// generic product used in most situations for simple products 
[Serializable]
public class GenericProduct : Product
{
    protected internal GenericProduct()
    {
    }

    public GenericProduct(String name, Decimal price) : base(name, price)
    {
    }
}

// custom product with additional properties and methods
[Serializable]
public class EventItem : Product
{
    protected internal EventItem()
    {
    }

    public EventItem(string name, decimal price) : base(name, price)
    {
    }
}

#endregion

#region EntityBase

[Serializable]
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    private readonly Guid _id;

    protected EntityBase() : this(GenerateGuidComb())
    {
    }

    protected EntityBase(Guid id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    public virtual Guid Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
    }

    private static Guid GenerateGuidComb()
    {
        var destinationArray = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
        var time = new DateTime(0x76c, 1, 1);
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var span = new TimeSpan(now.Ticks - time.Ticks);
        var timeOfDay = now.TimeOfDay;
        var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(span.Days);
        var array = BitConverter.GetBytes((long)(timeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds / 3.333333));
        Array.Reverse(bytes);
        Array.Reverse(array);
        Array.Copy(bytes, bytes.Length - 2, destinationArray, destinationArray.Length - 6, 2);
        Array.Copy(array, array.Length - 4, destinationArray, destinationArray.Length - 4, 4);
        return new Guid(destinationArray);
    }

    public virtual int Version { get; protected set; }

    #region Equality Tests

    public override bool Equals(object entity)
    {
        return entity != null
            && entity is EntityBase
            && this == (EntityBase)entity;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(EntityBase base1,
        EntityBase base2)
    {
        // check for both null (cast to object or recursive loop)
        if ((object)base1 == null && (object)base2 == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        // check for either of them == to null
        if ((object)base1 == null || (object)base2 == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (base1.Id != base2.Id)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(EntityBase base1, EntityBase base2)
    {
        return (!(base1 == base2));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        {
            return Id.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    #endregion

#endregion
}
```

}

Comment: Perhaps you could filter out some specific pieces of code that you want input on?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To be honest it is more of an architecture question rather than a specific problem with code.

Comment: Strategy pattern doesn't seem to be right to me, especially if you can have multiple discounts applied to the cart. To me your looking to implement some sort of rules engine.

Comment: @Chev Did you get any solution for this problem? as i am also trying to solve same problem discounts with priorities.

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in the comments to your question I don't think strategy is apt in this case.

To me all these discounts BuyXGetYFree, SpendMoreThanXGetYDiscount etc are all rules (and may not all neccesarily be about getting discount) that can be applied in calculating product/cart cost. I would build a RulesEngine utilising the rules you outlined and when you ask the cart to calculate its cost process it against the RulesEngine. The RulesEngine would process the product lines making up the cart and the overall order and apply the relevant adjustments to costs etc.

The RulesEngine could even control the order in which the rules are applied.

Rules could be product based (e.g. Buy one get one free) or order based (eg. Buy X items get free shipping) and you could even have expiry dates built in. These rules would be persisted to a data store.

Answer (score 3):

To me the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) seems more applicable here. It starts with the a similar Discount class hierarchy you have, but the discounts would also implement `OrderBase`. Then they decorate the order instead of just being attached to it. When queried, the decorator gets the order data from the order instance it decorates (which may be a plain vanilla order, or another decorator), and applies to it the appropriate discount. IMO this is fairly easy to implement but also flexible enough; in short, to me this is the *simplest solution that may work*.

The order of discounts in the decorator chain is probably not arbitrary though; at first guess you should apply price altering discounts first, then quantity altering ones. But I guess this is not a very strong constraint.

Comment: thanks for the reply Peter. Having a looking through decorator to see if it fits...